# Exception thrown while deploying spring batch job in SpringXD Singlenode

Tags: spring-batch, spring-xd

Exception thrown while deploying spring batch job in SpringXD Singlenode (1.2.0 Distribution)

Please let me know, how this exception can be fixed (or) any further details needed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid
   bean definition with name 'registrar' defined in class path resource 
   [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: 
Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"; 
   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not 
   resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"
```

Following are the trace

```
2015-07-24T15:29:11-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Deploying module [ModuleDescriptor@6435a6c5 moduleName = 'category', moduleLabel = 'category', group = 'testcategory', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = job, parameters = map['dateFormat' -> 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'makeUnique' -> 'true'], children = list[[empty]]]
2015-07-24T15:29:12-0700 1.2.0.RELEASE WARN DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'registrar' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) [spring-xd-module-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployJobModule(DeploymentListener.java:291) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.job.name' in string value "${xd.job.name}"
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of your ``registrar`` bean and your definition from ``job-module-beans.xml``? Also, you should improve the formatting of your post for sake of readability.

Comment: Thanks for your response - user1438038! Let me try to check formatting going forward.  I am not including the job-module-beans.xml in the application and  it is getting picked dynamically during job deploy.

Comment: Also wondering how the out of box job-module-beans.xml file (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/job/job-module-beans.xml) is getting dynamically picked during custom job deploy?

Comment: Do you provide a proper ``xd.job.name`` when deploying the jobs? It seems the value is missing.

Comment: thanks for the timely help user1438038!  The 'xd.job.name' value is matching  'definition' value  and now job execute without any errors

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to accept and upvote my answer, if it helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating your job, you will usually pass a `name` and `definition` argument. The `definition` will be put in `xd.job.name` that serves as a placeholder for the current job's name. It will be filled in, for example in `job-module-beans.xml`, when `xd.job.name` is referenced.

Check out this example:

```
xd:> job create --name helloWord --definition "hellojob" --deploy
xd:> job launch helloWord --params {"someStringParam":"foobar","-someOtherParam(long)":"123456"}
```

Make sure you pass the correct `definition` when creating your job during deployment.